# Pip downloads requierements that are already satisfied

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying install `tensorflow==1.14.0` but I have a very slow connection to internet, so I downloaded the `.whl` I needed from `pypi.org`. When I run:

```
~$ pip install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

It resolve the dependencies and starts to download `numpy==1.16.6` even if numpy is already installed on my system. I now because I run the python console and do:

```
bionic@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(np.__version__)
1.16.6
```

The problem is I'm testing a software and I need do this over and over and I don't want download numpy every time from pypi because I now it is already installed.
I'm using Ubuntu bionic (server). Thank you for your help and forgive my poor English.

Comment: You don't reinstall numpy everytime, when tensorflow tries to install it and sees it is already installed, it doesn't do anything and prints to the console, `Requirement already satisifed: ...`

Comment: The real problem is the way I installed numpy. If I install it from internet all is right. But, if I install it from a downloaded .whl then I have that problem.